# Button Click With Out this Screen Show Printing , Print using Wifi Printer ? Possible or Not

Tags: java, android-studio, printing, document, wifi-direct

[This screen should not appear and direct print to the printer on click of my application button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs2PH.jpg)

My mobile has Wi-Fi printer connected to it, so I have to print on the button of the application without showing the upper screen.